# Why swapping is not working when I am using method to swap two collections

Tags: java, collections, java-8, swap

**I come across one scenario where swapping is not working when I am using a method to swap two collections.**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Stack<Integer> one= new Stack<>();
    Stack<Integer> two= new Stack<>();
    one.push(1);
    one.push(2);
    swap(one, two);
    two.forEach(System.out::println);
}

//swap two stack
private static void swap(Stack<Integer> one, Stack<Integer> two) {
    Stack<Integer> temp = new Stack<>();
    temp = one;
    one = two;
    two = temp; 
}
```

**But When I swap two collections using below code, it does swap two collections.**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Stack<Integer> one= new Stack<>();
    Stack<Integer> two= new Stack<>();
    one.push(1);
    one.push(2);
    Stack<Integer> temp = new Stack<>();
    temp = one;
    one = two;
    two = temp;
    two.forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

I would really appreciate the help. Let me know if you want more clarification.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17563873/2010838

Might be useful.

Comment: Java is pass-by-value. You can not do this.

Comment: You can't write a swap method like that in Java.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot modify the callers' reference(s), but you can save the values from `one` in `temp`, clear `one`, add all of `two` to `one`, clear `two` and finally add `temp` to `two` - effectively performing your swap. Like,

```
private static void swap(Stack<Integer> one, Stack<Integer> two) {
    Stack<Integer> temp = new Stack<>();
    temp.addAll(one);
    one.clear();
    one.addAll(two);
    two.clear();
    two.addAll(temp);
}
```